# Why is my rock paper scissors script in JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript

I made a rock paper scissors script but everytime i click on 'pierre' only the first condition is showing even when he loses or tie.

Here is my code. (rock = pierre, paper = papier, scissors = ciseaux)

```
let pierre = document.getElementById('pierre');
let papier = document.getElementById('papier');
let ciseaux = document.getElementById('ciseaux');
let random = ['papier', 'pierre','ciseaux'];


let choix = () =>
   random[Math.floor(Math.random() * random.length)];



    pierre.onclick = function oui (){
        choix();
        console.log(choix());
        if(random[2]){
            pierre.style.background = ('green');
            ciseaux.style.background = ('red');
        }
        else if (random[0]){
            pierre.style.background = ('orange');
            ciseaux.style.background = ('orange');
        }
        else if (random[1]){
            pierre.style.background = ('red');
            ciseaux.style.background = ('green');
        };
    };
```

Comment: You need to store the result of the `choix()` call, then compare that against the three `random`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
if (random[2]) {
```

, write this:

```
let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * random.length);
if (i == 2) {
```

Please note that `random[2]` is `'cisaeux'`, which is always true.

Answer (score 0):

You need to *pick* one of your choices, at the moment it seems you are not, do something like:

```
let pierre = document.getElementById('pierre');
let papier = document.getElementById('papier');
let ciseaux = document.getElementById('ciseaux');
let choices = ['papier', 'pierre','ciseaux'];

let choix = () =>
  // Here pick one from choices:
  let random = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];

  pierre.onclick = function oui (){
    choix();
    console.log(choix());
    if(random[2]){
        pierre.style.background = ('green');
        ciseaux.style.background = ('red');
    }
    else if (random[0]){
        pierre.style.background = ('orange');
        ciseaux.style.background = ('orange');
    }
    else if (random[1]){
        pierre.style.background = ('red');
        ciseaux.style.background = ('green');
    };
};
```

Comment: like this :
let choix = () =>
   choices[1];
let random = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];

Comment: No, as in the code i posted, and exactly like @pts posted :)

Answer (score 0):

You have most of the code that you need. What you need to change is:

1. Capture the return value of `const result  = choix();` and then
2. check your conditions on the `result` value.

   ```
   let pierre = document.getElementById('pierre');
   let papier = document.getElementById('papier');
   let ciseaux = document.getElementById('ciseaux');
   let random = ['papier', 'pierre','ciseaux'];

   let choix = () =>
      random[Math.floor(Math.random() * random.length)];

   pierre.onclick = function oui (){
       // User clicked on rock

       // Calculate CPU result
       const result  = choix();

       if(result === 'ciseaux'){
           // CPU chice is scissors, rock wins
           pierre.style.background = ('green');
           ciseaux.style.background = ('red');
       }
       else if (result === 'pierre'){
           // CPU choice is rock - draw
           pierre.style.background = ('orange');
       }
       else if (result === 'papier'){
           // CPU choice is paper - paper wins
           pierre.style.background = ('red');
           papier.style.background = ('green');
       };
   };
   ```

Note: calling `choix()` will yield a random value each time. The function returns a string and not an integer. I only mention this because your code has two calls to `choix()` one of which is a console log.

The reason it always selects the first case in your code is `random[2]` is the string `'ciseaux'` which is a "truthy" value

Answer (score 0):

You need to change all the `if (random[x])` parts to `if (choix == random[x])`, to check which part of the if...else if...else if condition gets fulfilled. I would also advise you to use switch conditional instead of if else, since you can only choose between 3 types of specific answers.